# Mutt: load message headers lazily

Tags: mutt

When mutt opens some folder, it downloads (or gets from the cache) headers of *all* messages from that folder. I find it very suboptimal.

It doesn't hurt too much when the folder contains just a few messages, but when I open some really large folder in mutt (for example, the folder containing messages from Linux Kernel Mailing List: I currently have almost 300 000 messages there), it takes forever to download. Even with the whole list totally cached, it seems it still refreshes some data, and it takes about 2 minutes to open that folder even when it's cached! This is just ridiculous. It's a waste of space and time.

Even more, 300 000 messages is probably too much for mutt, and when I hit `q`, it just hangs (I was patient enough to wait more than 5 mins).

I don't see any good reason to download *all* message headers. I want message headers to be loaded lazily, i.e. on demand: we just need to load a page to display, plus probably a few pages ahead, but the rest should be loaded only when the user scrolls there. Surprizingly enough, I can't find an option for that. Do I miss something, or is it impossible to setup lazy loading in mutt?

Comment: Are you already using disk cache?  If not, you might be satisfied enough with not always using memory every time.  (header_cache)

Comment: Of course I am, I mentioned that in my question: "Even with the whole list totally cached, it seems it still refreshes some data, and it takes about 2 minutes to open that folder even when it's cached! This is just ridiculous. It's a waste of space and time"

Comment: Yeah, I'll definitely let you know if I see anything.  After a lot of searching I didn't see any way to limit the number of message you want to see/download.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that your config has the right entries for caching and that the used mutt version supports caching. See here: